# How do I properly "slice" a 4D matrix in Matlab in a parfor loop?

Tags: matlab, parfor

I am trying to make a portion of my code run faster in MatLab, and I'd like to use parfor. When I try to, I get the following error about one of my variables `D_all`.

"The PARFOR loop cannot run because of the way D_all is used".

Here is a sample of my code.

```
M = 161;
N = 24;
P = 161;

parfor n=1:M*N*P
   [j,i,k] = ind2sub([N,M,P],n);

   r0 = Rw(n,1:3);
   R0 = repmat(r0,M*N*P,1);

   delta = sqrt(dXnd(i)^2 + dZnd(k)^2);

   d = R_prime - R0;

   inS = Rw_prime(find(sqrt(sum(d.^2,2))<0.8*delta),:);

   if isempty(inS)
            D_all(j,i,k,tj) = D_all(j,i,k,tj-1);
   else
            y0 = r0(2);

            inC = inS(find(inS(:,2)==y0),:);

            dw = sqrt(sum(d(find(sqrt(sum(d.^2,2))<0.8*delta & d(:,2)==0),:).^2,2));

            V_avg = sum(dw.^(-1).*inC(:,4))/sum(dw.^(-1));

            D_all(j,i,k,tj) = V_avg;
   end
end
```

I'm not very familiar with parallel computing, and I've looked at the guides online and don't really understand how to apply them to my situation. I guess I need to "slice" `D_all` but I don't know how to do that.

**EDIT**: I think I understand that the major problem is that when using `D_all` I have `tj` and `tj-1`.

**EDIT 2**: I don't show this above, it probably would have been helpful, but I defined `D_all(:,:,:,1) = V_1;` where `V_1` corresponds to a previous time step. I tried making multiple variables `V_2`, `V_3`, etc. for each step and replacing `D_all(j,i,k,tj-1)` with `V_1(j,i,k)`. This still led to the same error I am seeing with `D_all`.

"Valid indices for D_all are restricted for PARFOR loops"

Comment: In a `parfor` each iteration must be independent of the others. Iterations are executed in arbitrary order. You cannot depend on the previous result.

Comment: See Edit 1 and 2.

Comment: Yes, I saw what you wrote. Changing the name doesn’t change the problem. You cannot depend on a previous time step because **iterations are executed in arbitrary order**. Your problem doesn’t translate to parallel execution. You cannot do what you want to do in parallel.

Comment: If you want help speeding up your code, post a [mcve], including example input and output data.

Comment: I didn't change the name. What I actually did was create new variables. One for each time step. Then I tried calling that variable inside an if statement depending on the time step.  Either way, what I did didn't work.

Comment: There is no way to verify the example because I cannot possibly upload all the data that I use in my calculations. I can implement suggestions on my end and respond, but that's the limitation of this type question.